# Spring transaction rollback

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I have been trying to figure this out for two days without sucess. I am using annotation-driven transactions with Spring 3.0.5 and Postgress. I am calling two dao methods from a business logic method:

```
@Transactional 
public void registerTransaction(GoogleTransaction transaction) {
       long transactionID = DBFactory.getTransactionDBInstance().addTransaction(transaction);
       DBFactory.getGoogleTransactionDBInstance().addGoogleTransaction(transaction, transactionID);

}
```

The second method (addGoogleTransaction) throws a RuntimeException at the end, however transaction is not rolled back and both rows are inserted.

The DAO method looks like this:

```
public void addGoogleTransaction(GoogleTransaction transaction, long id) {
    log.trace("Entering addGoogleTransaction DAO method ");
    log.trace(transaction.toString());
    getSimpleJdbcTemplate().update(QRY_ADD_GOOGLE_TRANSACTION, new Object[] {id, transaction.getGoogleSerialNumber() ,
        transaction.getGoogleBuyerID(), transaction.getGoogleOrderID()});
    log.trace("Google transaction added successfully");
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

The Spring configuration file:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

Do I need to configure something else? I have tried to add @Transactional to the business logic class and @Transactional to the dao methods but it doesn't work neither.
Thanx

It is called from a controller class (annotated with @Controller) for testing pursposes.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration")
public String sendToRegistrationPage() throws ServiceException {

    GoogleTransaction googleTransaction = new GoogleTransaction(0, "aei", new Date(), TransactionStatus.NEW, BigDecimal.ZERO, "", "", 0, "");
    BillingFactory.getBillingImplementation("").registerTransaction(googleTransaction);
    return "registration";
}
```

Comment: Where do you call registerTransaction from? Can you include this code? What classes do these methods belong to?

Comment: "however transaction is not rolled back and both rows are inserted." -- wich transaction do you mean: the GoogleTransaction?

Comment: I added the coded where it is called. Is this important?

Comment: Dao methods are in a class that inherits SimpleJdbcDaoSupport. The registerTransaction logic method is in a different package and class where all the business logic classes are.

Comment: Ralph, both transactions are not rolled back. I want that both transactions commit or fail. Thanks

Comment: The calling code shows your BillingImplementation is not instantiated by spring so it won't be wrapped with a transactional proxy. Therefore all your database calls are autocommited since @Transactional annotations are ignored. Also use @<nick> in your comments, otherwise its author won't be notifed by stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what `BillingFactory.getBillingImplementation("")` does. Is it a plain Java factory or does ist return a Spring service from the application context? I'm also not sure if you have Spring transactional proxies - if not then what you do is very likely autocommited. I think it'd be a good idea to enable logging for the package `org.springframework.transaction`.

Actually I'd expect something like:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Resource
    private BillingService billingService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration")
    public String sendToRegistrationPage() throws ServiceException {
        GoogleTransaction googleTransaction = new GoogleTransaction(0, "aei", new Date(), TransactionStatus.NEW, BigDecimal.ZERO, "", "", 0, "");
        billingService.registerTransaction(googleTransaction);
        return "registration";
    }
}
```

And in your Spring config something like (or some `@Service` annotated bean):

```
<bean id="billingService" class="foo.bar.BillingImplementation" />
```

Comment: Thank you. It is a plain Java factory that just returns a new instance of the logic bean. I am sorry I will read more about proxies and Ioc. But in order to work does Spring has to inject the billingService? why? As far as I understand Spring injects at startup, does it mean that billingService has to be singleton so I can get always the same instance that Spring injected?

Comment: @Oscar: A plain Java factory won't work. The injection of the bean is not the important part but it's creation by a Spring bean factory in order to make `@Transactional` work. Otherwise this annotation is just ignored.

Comment: @Oscar: Yes, Spring beans are singletons per default.

Comment: @Oscar: For further reading I'd suggest http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html.

Comment: In your example why if I don't use @Resource and just get the  billingService via its static factory method, the transaction doesn't work? billingService is a singleton and it is created by spring at startup. Does creating and injection have different meaning?
Thanks

Comment: @Oscar: Yes, `billingService` is a singleton per default. When it's created by the Spring container it get's wrapped with a transactional proxy because of the `@Transactional` annotation (and `<tx:annotation-driven />`). This won't happen if you create the `billingService` via a static factory method. As Spring follows the IoC principle, services are typically injected.